# Is there any way to restart Solr using Java?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm using SolrJ to index my datas in my solr core. I use Solr's autocommit and I want to restart my solr when indexing is finish. Is there any way to do this with java codes??

I did something like this

```
    String urlReload="http://localhost:8983/solr";
    HttpSolrClient solr_reload=new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlReload).build();
    CoreAdminRequest adminRequest=new CoreAdminRequest();
    adminRequest.setAction(CoreAdminAction.RELOAD);
    adminRequest.setCoreName("archiveCore");
    adminRequest.process(solr_reload);
```

Comment: Can you see if reload works for you? https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-reload

Comment: Why do you want to restart Solr after indexing?

Comment: @MatsLindh When I don't restart after indexing I don't see any datas in my solr core. When I'm restarting or reloading my core the datas is coming.

Comment: Sounds like you're are committing the data without opening a new searcher - or not committing at all (but then the data should disappear). Add `commitWithin=10000` to make sure any data sent appears within 10 seconds after being submitted, or send an explicit commit request, and make sure that you're opening a new searcher when committing.

Comment: @MatsLindh Is it working with `autoCommit`?

Comment: That depends on whether you've configured autoCommit to open a new searcher.

Comment: It's better to reload cores than just restarting the solr itself

Comment: OK. How do I reload my core using SolrJ? Do you know any way?

Answer (score 0):

Do `solr_reload.commit()` at last. Then you don't need to restart solr.